# Show VM descriptions on VirtualBox from terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualbox, debian-based

Please help,
I've server for development on debian 8 host using Virtualbox. I try to use and learn terminal for work with all activity, I think it more efficient.
I know to list and run vm on terminal.

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
$ VBoxManage startvm <vm name> --type headless
```

But, I can't show the desctriptions from terminal. because I store all information on descriptions.
I've try to read man page VBoxMAnage, and search on google.

Asked : How to show vm descriptions on terminal?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't show the desctriptions from terminal.

Try:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo <vm name>
```

and look:

```
Description:
<description>
```

Comment: Hi Gluttton, Thank you for response. Ohh sorry, I did not notice on VBoxManage showvminfo. Next time, I'll read man page word by word.. sorry..